# Mono for Android linking exception

Tags: android, exception, mono, apk, xamarin.android

I have a problem with a small app I'm trying to build. When I turn on linking, I've tried both  SDK Assemblies only and SDK and user assemblies, I get the same exception when I'm trying to build an APK.

Exception:

```
System.Exception: The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
  at Mono.Cecil.PE.ByteBuffer.ReadUInt32()
  at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadOperand(Instruction instruction)
  ...
```

I get exactly the same exception when I just create a new Mono project and try to build an APK with linking turned on.

Grateful for any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception comes from `Mono.Cecil.dll`, i.e. the library on which the linker is based. That's quite uncommon and it will need to be debugged.

I can't even propose a workaround (except not linking) without knowing more about how that assembly was generated (e.g. compiler, obfustactor...)

Can you fill a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and attach the *offending* assembly ? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Before I saw your reply I tried to reinstall Mono for android and the problem disappeared. But if I encounter the problem again I'll fill out the bug report.